# LocalDate.parse can't parse the character on the last index wehere there is no character (nor empty space)

Tags: java, java-time

I have in my notepad file text:

```
19-12-2021
```

I checked is there any empty spaces, there is none.

When I write:

```
String noticeLastUpdateDate = textFileDAO.getMoneyTableNoticeLastUpdateDate();
DateTimeFormatter formatterDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate dateNow = LocalDate.parse(noticeLastUpdateDate, formatterDate);
```

I receive an error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '19-12-2021
' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

But there is no index 10! Why it thinks there is index[10]?

Comment: From the error message, there is clearly a trailing new line character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim possible whitespaces before parsing the date using `String::trim`:

```java
String trimmedDate = textFileDAO.getMoneyTableNoticeLastUpdateDate().trim();
DateTimeFormatter formatterDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate dateNow = LocalDate.parse(trimmedDate, formatterDate);
```